# Is there a way to get rid of chrome password manager when input is the focus?

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, password-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAqo7.jpg)

Disabled Chrome's password manager option when input is focused.
But the password manager keeps popping up. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try turning off Chromes autocomplete feature? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: I turned off chrome's autocomplete and applied ' autocomplete="off" ' to no avail. Thank you for your reply.